# HTMLInputElement forwardRef doesn't accept name

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-sunset-vzx79).

Here is my input component:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react'

type Props = {
  err: boolean
  maxWidth: string
}

export const Input = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, Props>(({ ...rest }, ref) => {
  return <StyledInput {...rest} ref={ref} />
})

const StyledInput = styled.input<Props>``
```

Here is usage:

```
<Input name='password' type='password' autoComplete='password' required />
```

Why name gives me error (as i can see other props have error too):

```
Type '{ name: string; type: string; autoComplete: string; required: true; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & RefAttributes<HTMLInputElement>'.
  Property 'name' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & RefAttributes<HTMLInputElement>'.ts(2322)
```

When default react interface has this prop:

```
interface HTMLInputElement extends HTMLElement {
    name: string;
    /**
     * Gets or sets a string containing a regular expression that the user's input must match.
     */
}
```

Comment: Do one of the others Omit the name attribute for some reason?

Comment: @JoeLloyd sorry, don't understand question.

Comment: Sorry my suggestion wouldn't work anyway, just saw your Props interface. Thought maybe it was using Omit on name.

Answer (score 2):

The first type in `forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, Props>` only specifies the `ref` type, so you can't pass the properties inside `HTMLInputElement` as props.

Instead, you should expand your `Props` type by adding the `HTMLInputElement` type as an option.

```
type Props = {
  err: boolean
  maxWidth: string
} & HTMLInputElement
```

However, in this case, you will be required to provide all 200-something properties of `HTMLInputElement` as props to your `Input`. That's no good, but `Typescript` has a neat little trick for that. You can use `Partial<HTMLInputElement>` instead.

```
type Props = {
  err: boolean
  maxWidth: string
} & Partial<HTMLInputElement>
```

Now, you'll be required to provide your own defined props (`err` and `maxWidth`) and you can optionally provide any property from `HTMLInputElement`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you provide full code? With only "& Partial<HTMLInputElement>" another errors popup.

Comment: What's the error? I suspect one of them is `autoComplete`. You should write `autocomplete` instead. Also, you have to provide `err` and `maxWidth` as props, since they are required. If you want them to be optional too, add `err?` and `maxWidth?` in `Props` type definition.

Comment: you can use codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-sunset-vzx79

Comment: It looks like `styled-components` package has a mismatch in the internal types with `HTMLInputElement`, so you can't use that interface. My answer fixes the adding optional props to your own component problem, but you'll have to read more about the package issue here https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/630

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution:

```
interface Props extends React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'input'> {
  err?: boolean
  maxWidth?: string
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should declare your Props type as below

```
static propTypes = {
      name: PropTypes.string,
      ...
 }
```

I hope this will help!

Comment: elaborate more on this